# How to show longitude and latitude in map using jquery mobile +phonegap (android)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am able to get longitude and latitude in phonegap  .Now i need to show this on map view .Is there any jquery or phonegap library to show in map? I need jquery mobile code so that it will run on both android as well as in Ios.

```
var lng = 0;
//A button click will call this function
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    //Lat long will be fetched and stored in session variables
    //These variables will be used while storing data in local database 
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
   // alert('Lattitude: ' + lat + ' Longitude: ' + lng);
    sessionStorage.setItem('lattitude', lat);
    sessionStorage.setItem('longitude', lng);
}
// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}var lng = 0;
//A button click will call this function
function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    //Lat long will be fetched and stored in session variables
    //These variables will be used while storing data in local database 
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
   // alert('Lattitude: ' + lat + ' Longitude: ' + lng);
    sessionStorage.setItem('lattitude', lat);
    sessionStorage.setItem('longitude', lng);
}
// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely easy when working with jQuery Mobile + a small Google framework called **`GMAP API v3`**.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7kGdE/

**`CSS`** is important here because data-role="content" will by default not cover whole page so we need to force it to cover available space.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="content">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index',function(e,data){    
   // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
   var minZoomLevel = 12;

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: minZoomLevel,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Google Maps JavaScript API. You'll be able to include a map in your application just using JavaScript and HTML. All the info to accomplish this is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). And if you want to show the actual position of the coordinates, you can insert a [maker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers)